# Given a solution point with variables x, y , and z, how can you find f(x,y) of an implicit function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, taylor-expansion, implicit-function

$$g(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 - z^2 - xyz = 12$$

Given a solution point $(x,y,z) = (3,4,1)$, write the first order Taylor Formula centered at $f(3,4)$ A unique continuous implicit function $z = f(x,y)$ exists.

The correct answer for the problem is $f(3,4) = 1$. However, I am not quite sure how to arrive at that. I have written down the working I have done, but I am not sure it's done the correct way. I do not need help with writing the Taylor formula, just finding $f(3,4)$.

$$g(3,4,1) = 12$$
$$f(3,4) = 3^2 + 4^2 - 0^2 - ((3)(4)(0)) - g(3,4,1) = 13-12 = 1$$

Please let me know if this working is correct. Thank you in advance

Comment: I apologize @IvanKaznacheyeu. I have added some key context to the problem.

Comment: I suppose first order formula must include linear terms like $f(x,y)=1+a(x-3)+b(y-4)$. Of course, one can find exact values of $a$ and $b$ from $g(x,y,z)$.

Answer (score 1):

The first order approximation of $f(x,y)$ around $(3,4)$is given by
$$
f(x,y) \approx f(3,4) + f'_x(3,4)(x-3) + f'_y(3,4)(y-4)
$$

You already concluded that $f(3,4)=1$, now you must obtain the partial derivatives at $(3,4)$. You can either use the formula from the implicit function theorem, or derive the equality with respect to $x$ and $y$. For instance, deriving

$$
x^2+y^2-f(x,y)^2- x y f(x,y)=12
$$

with respect to $x$ gives you
$$
2x + 2 f'_x(x,y) f(x,y)-y(f(x,y) + x f'_x(x,y))=0. 
$$
so,

$$
f'_x(x,y)=\dfrac{y f(x,y) - 2x}{2f(x,y)-xy}.
$$

Substituting $(x,y)=(3,4)$ yields
$$
f'_x(3,4) = \frac{4\times 1 - 2\times 3}{2 \times 1 - 3\times 4 } = \frac 15
$$

Do the same for $f'_y(3,4)$ and you'll have your result.